# Express unable to bind to port 443 on Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, express

We launched a major update to our Node app tonight and could not get our Express app to bind to 443 for our SSL Endpoint...

```
var httpsOptions = {
    key: fs.readFileSync( __dirname + '/certs/' + config.ssl.key),
    cert: fs.readFileSync( __dirname + '/certs/' + config.ssl.crt)
};
httpsServer = https.Server(httpsOptions, app);
httpsServer.listen(config.httpsPort, function(){
console.info("HTTPS listening on port " + config.httpsPort);
});
```

(config.httpsPort = 443)

```
2015-02-01T07:13:27.151996+00:00 app[web.1]: Bugsnag: Error: listen EACCES
2015-02-01T07:13:27.152004+00:00 app[web.1]: at errnoException (net.js:905:11)
2015-02-01T07:13:27.152005+00:00 app[web.1]: at Server.listen2 (net.js:1024:19)
2015-02-01T07:13:27.152007+00:00 app[web.1]: at Server._listen2 (/app/node_modules/newrelic/node_modules/continuation-local-storage/node_modules/async-listener/index.js:71:23)
2015-02-01T07:13:27.152008+00:00 app[web.1]: at listen (net.js:1065:10)
2015-02-01T07:13:27.152010+00:00 app[web.1]: at Server.listen (net.js:1139:5)
2015-02-01T07:13:27.152012+00:00 app[web.1]: at Server. (/app/server.js:110:25)
2015-02-01T07:13:27.152015+00:00 app[web.1]: at Server.g (events.js:180:16)
2015-02-01T07:13:27.152017+00:00 app[web.1]: at Server.emit (events.js:92:17)
2015-02-01T07:13:27.152019+00:00 app[web.1]: at net.js:1056:10
2015-02-01T07:13:27.152021+00:00 app[web.1]: at /app/nodemodules/newrelic/node_modules/continuation-local-storage/node_modules/async-listener/glue.js:188:31
2015-02-01T07:13:27.152023+00:00 app[web.1]: at /app/node_modules/newrelic/node_modules/continuation-local-storage/node_modules/async-listener/glue.js:188:31
2015-02-01T07:13:27.152026+00:00 app[web.1]: at process.tickDomainCallback (node.js:486:13)
2015-02-01T07:13:27.152027+00:00 app[web.1]: at process. (/app/nodemodules/newrelic/node_modules/continuation-local-storage/node_modules/async-listener/index.js:18:15)
```

This code is nearly identical to the earlier version and the earlier version worked just fine.

Comment: There might be a chance that the cause of this is related to permissions, if you're not running the code as a root then try to run it under root user "or sudo", on the other hand, you might also want to check if the port is not already in use, try to check the output of the command `lsof -i:443` and see its status.

Answer (score 2):

All ports below 1024 are privileged - only a root user can bind to it.

On Heroku web dyno, you should bind only to port specified by `PORT` env var, because Heroku expects to find a running application there. If you don't, it will shut your web dyno after 60 seconds with [R10 Boot Timeout](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/error-codes#r10-boot-timeout) error message.

Also you can't bind HTTPS there, because Heroku runs a loadbalancer before, and it terminates SSL/TLS. Your web dyno receives plain HTTP traffic.

Answer (score 0):

While I don't understand how the previous version was working under appa on heroku and very similar code on appb was not, the issue was I did not understand how Heroku routing worked.  You always bind to the port they give you, even if you have SSL endpoint.